# Development resources for Mono on PS3

Tags: c#, mono, playstation

I have been considering taking the plunge and installing Linux on my Playstation 3.  As C# is my current language of choice, the next logical step would be to install Mono.

I have done a little research and found that http://psubuntu.com/wiki/InstallationInstructions has instruction on installing Ubuntu and links to download an ISO containing a PS3 specific version of Ubuntu.  There is also this cool project at http://code.google.com/p/celldotnet/ that has developed some code to utilize the 6 additional SPU cores of the CPU, not just the general-purpose one that you have access to by default.

The problem is that the project documentation seems a little thin.  Has anyone set up a PS3 to develop .NET code?  If so, what problems did you encounter?  Does anyone have any code samples of how to even partially load up one of these monster processors?

**Update:**

I do realize that basic .NET/Mono programming will come into play here.  The part I am fuzzy on is what sort of data structures do you pass to a specialty core?  If I am reading this right, [the 6 SPU cores have 128 registers at 128 bits each](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_processor#Synergistic_Processing_Elements_.28SPE.29).  I haven't seen any discussion on how to go about coding effectively for this.

**Update 2:**

[IBM has announced](http://arstechnica.com/hardware/news/2009/11/end-of-the-line-for-ibms-cell.ars) that further development on the Cell processor has been cancelled.  While this pretty much kills any desire I might have to develop on the platform, hopefully someone else might add some useful info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found [this posting](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Feb-26.html) from Miguel de Icaza's blog.  Promising that as recently as Feb 2008 he was looking into this.  As he is [a member of the SO community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16929/migueldeicaza) now, I hope he can shed some further light on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The PS3 features a PPC general purpose CPU.

You can try to cross compile mono to ppc and go from there.

Mono from svn has received a lot of attention regarding the ppc port, so I would advise using it instead of the 2.0 release.