# Developing an application for the PS3

Tags: playstation3

Is it possible to create an application (not a game) on the PS3? I know that there are ways to install Linux and all that but I was hoping there's something which you can just download from the net and run. I'd want the app to run like a server/daemon and be able to access the network.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might find the following to be of interest.

#### From StackOverflow:

- [Develop for Playstation 3 Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467711/develop-for-playstation-3-linux)
- [Development Resources for Mono on Playstation 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153/development-resources-for-mono-on-ps3)
- [How do I Code a Mono Daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186493/how-do-i-code-a-mono-daemon)

---

#### Programming high-performance applications on the Cell BE processor

- Part 1: [An introduction to Linux on the PLAYSTATION 3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/library/pa-linuxps3-1/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX16&S_CMP=EDU)
- Part 2: [Program the synergistic processing elements of the Sony PLAYSTATION 3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/library/pa-linuxps3-2/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX16&S_CMP=EDU)
- Part 3: [Meet the synergistic processing unit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/library/pa-linuxps3-3/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX16&S_CMP=EDU)
- Part 4: [Program the SPU for performance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/library/pa-linuxps3-4/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX16&S_CMP=EDU)

---

*Interesting, but probably not what you're looking for:*

Learn and Compete in Programming the PLAYSTATION®3 Cell Processor ([source](http://www.cag.csail.mit.edu/ps3/))

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can program for the PS3 is through Linux. You don't get access to the "real" SDK unless you can secure a contract with Sony, and you're making a AAA game.

Everyone else have to target Linux.

Comment: Technically you can also hook into the boot loader and run your application directly on the hypervisor, meaning your application needs to be written in assembly. Of course this far more tedious, but it's been done.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking of officially supported ways to code for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also develop a BD-Java (BD-J) application for PS3.